# How to edit this popup in Jhipster?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, jhipster

[Popup in Jhipster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s87Dr.png)

I don't know how to edit this popup , I can't find the file where it is modified. I use react for the front-end

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Notification content is built by java backend in REST controller and passed to client through HTTP headers (i18n message key and its params)

```java
.headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
```

When frontend receives response, the popup is built in `notification-middleware.ts`, the message key is extracted for translation to retrieve localized message template and then the params are injected to produce final localized text:

```js
toast.success(translate(alert, { param: alertParam }));
```

You can see the headers when inspecting the response in the browser's console.

So, if you want to change the text for one entity, you must modify the message with "created" key in `src/main/webapp/i18n/<Language>/<Entity name>.json` for each language that your app supports.